# Parse script in string format to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to parse a string that comes from a database into useable JSON in Node.js

This is the string

```
"<script type=\"application/json\">\n[\n    {\n        \"id\": \"test1_label\",\n        \"variants\": [\n            {\n                \"name\": \"when-all\",\n                \"values\": [\n                    {\n                        \"main\": false,\n                        \"name\": \"test1_label\",\n                        \"type\": \"swatch\",\n                        \"property\": \"@background-color\",\n                        \"value\": \"primary-dark\",\n                        \"id\": \"34543\"\n                    }\n                ]\n            }\n        ]\n    }\n]\n</script>"
```

The data that is saved looks like this and I am trying to get it back to this original format once retrieved.

```
[
    {
        "id": "test1_label",
        "variants": [
            {
                "name": "when-all",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "main": false,
                        "name": "test1_label",
                        "type": "swatch",
                        "property": "@background-color",
                        "value": "primary-dark",
                        "id": "34543"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I've tried to use replace with regex to clean it up and then parse it but no luck.

Comment: Why are you just not downloading the JSON from the database? Fix the issue at the server end.

Comment: That string isn't valid JSON. It's HTML. You could use the DOM parser and extract the JSON.

Comment: I do not have access to the server, this is 3rd party data and how they are storing it. The JSON is added in an embed code block so they modify it to this format.

Comment: Please don't post your answer in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since this is html and not valid JSON it needed an HTML parser as pointed out by @jabaa and his answer is perfect if doing this from a browser where the DOM Parser is available

In my case I was getting the data in a Node.js environment so I had to use a DOM Parser and opted for himalaya

#### Solution

```
import { parse } from 'himalaya';
const embed = "<script type=\"application/json\">\n[\n    {\n        \"id\": \"test1_label\",\n        \"variants\": [\n            {\n                \"name\": \"when-all\",\n                \"values\": [\n                    {\n                        \"main\": false,\n                        \"name\": \"test1_label\",\n                        \"type\": \"swatch\",\n                        \"property\": \"@background-color\",\n                        \"value\": \"primary-dark\",\n                        \"id\": \"34543\"\n                    }\n                ]\n            }\n        ]\n    }\n]\n</script>"
const dom = parse(embed);
JSON.parse(dom[0].children[0].content)
```

Answer (score 2):

That string isn't valid JSON. It's HTML. You could use the DOM parser and extract the JSON.

```
const html =
  '<script type="application/json">\n[\n    {\n        "id": "test1_label",\n        "variants": [\n            {\n                "name": "when-all",\n                "values": [\n                    {\n                        "main": false,\n                        "name": "test1_label",\n                        "type": "swatch",\n                        "property": "@background-color",\n                        "value": "primary-dark",\n                        "id": "34543"\n                    }\n                ]\n            }\n        ]\n    }\n]\n</script>';

const parser = new DOMParser();

const htmlElement = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

const json = htmlElement.firstChild.textContent;
const array = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(array);
```

`parseFromString` creates an HTML element containing the script element. `firstChild` is the script element. `textContent` is the JSON string inside the script element. You can parse the JSON string to an array and use it as usual.

This code doesn't work in the stack snippet, but I've tested it on my local machine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I am using node and done have access to the DOM Parser. So I found a solution using Himalaya that is working great

https://github.com/andrejewski/himalaya

Comment: @AndyJamesN You should post an answer to your own question with your solution. That way it will benefit others with the same question.

Comment: I updated my question with a solution.. would it be better to add an answer?

Comment: @AndyJamesN Yeah, an answer is better. It's totally fine posting an answer to your own question. I do that pretty often (post a question just to post an answer) if it's something I haven't found a solution for on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just remove the `<script>` wrapper and then parse the JSON data?

```js
const dataStr = "<script type=\"application/json\">\n[\n    {\n        \"id\": \"test1_label\",\n        \"variants\": [\n            {\n                \"name\": \"when-all\",\n                \"values\": [\n                    {\n                        \"main\": false,\n                        \"name\": \"test1_label\",\n                        \"type\": \"swatch\",\n                        \"property\": \"@background-color\",\n                        \"value\": \"primary-dark\",\n                        \"id\": \"34543\"\n                    }\n                ]\n            }\n        ]\n    }\n]\n</script>";

function getData(dataStr) {
  JSON.parse(
    return dataStr
      .replace(/^<script type="application\/json"\>/, "")
      .replace(/<\/script>$/, "")
  );
}

console.log(getData(dataStr));
```

Comment: Why do you need a regular expression to remove a static string at the beginning and the end? You could use `dataStr.substring(32, dataStr.length - 9)`.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution.
@AndyJamesN

```
let scriptData  = "<script type=\"application/json\">\n[\n    {\n        \"id\": \"test1_label\",\n        \"variants\": [\n            {\n                \"name\": \"when-all\",\n                \"values\": [\n                    {\n                        \"main\": false,\n                        \"name\": \"test1_label\",\n                        \"type\": \"swatch\",\n                        \"property\": \"@background-color\",\n                        \"value\": \"primary-dark\",\n                        \"id\": \"34543\"\n                    }\n                ]\n            }\n        ]\n    }\n]\n</script>"

let finalJSON =  JSON.parse(scriptData.substring(

    scriptData.indexOf("["), 

scriptData.lastIndexOf("]") + 1
));
console.log(finalJSON);
```